# Stopping animation that uses TimeOut with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using the jQuery's `animate()` function along with TimeOut() to create a ticker effect.
Since the code is a bit long, and to better understand the effect, I uploaded the code to [JSBin (click to see)](http://jsbin.com/edepe4/edit). The animation works great, but I want to make it **pause** when a user hovers with a mouse.

The most important part of the code (if you haven't gone to the JSBin link) that creates the ticker effect is:

```
var stocksTicker = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#ticker li:first').animate({
            marginTop: '-27px'
        }, 800, function () {
            $(this).detach().appendTo('#ticker');
        });
        stocksTicker();
    }, 4000);
};
stocksTicker();​
```

I tried to make the pause effect by using the following code:

```
$('#ticker li').hover(function () {
    $('#ticker li:first').stop();
}, function () {
    stocksTicker();
});
```

but using this just messes up the whole animation ([you can view the result here](http://jsbin.com/edepe4/2/edit)).

How can I get a normal pause effect that will not mess up my animation?

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a check in there to gracefully stop(i.e. it finishes the animation if it's already started).  Also I would use setInterval instead of setTimeout:

```
var run = true;
var stocksTicker = function()
{

      setInterval(function(){
        if(run){
            $('#ticker li:first').animate( {marginTop: '-27px'}, 800, function()
            {
                $(this).detach().appendTo('#ticker').removeAttr('style');
            });
        }
      }, 4000);

};
$('#ticker li').hover(
  function(){
     run = false; 
  },
  function(){
     run = true;
  });
stocksTicker();​
```

Comment: Very smooth, liked the idea to let it finish the current run before stopping it!

Answer (score 2):

you can use **[clearTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)**

```
var tmr = null;
var stocksTicker = function () {
    tmr = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#ticker li:first').animate({
            marginTop: '-27px'
        }, 800, function () {
            $(this).detach().appendTo('#ticker').removeAttr('style');
        });
        stocksTicker();
    }, 1000);

};
stocksTicker();

$('#ticker li').hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(tmr)
}, function () {
    stocksTicker();
});
```

### [Try it here](http://jsbin.com/edepe4/3)